# Keep files in dist folder after build step (nestjs)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a nestjs app that stores uploaded files on disk in the dist folder ('public/images/...'). However, if

> npm run build

is run, the images are deleted, since this build step deletes the entire dist folder.

What is the best way keep the images after the build task is run?

Comment: Hey you can change the destination of uploaded files to somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

look I was facing your problem I solve it by
install  `cpx`  also add in the package.json
my example in the Graphql it will be cd to your path you want to move it
just need to change  dependent on your path and what folder or file want to  move it in the build file just tell me if it works or not

```
"postbuild": "cd src && cpx schema.graphql ../build",
```